# Copy ZIP file into Artifactory without any meta-data using Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, artifactory

I have a Spring Boot `2.x` project that uses Gradle `7.x`.

I'm assembling a *distribution* of the artifact/service in a `zip` / `tar` file using the built-in Spring Boot task(s) provided. There is no meta-data associated with this asset, nor any need to add anything else to it.

I would like to copy (or publish) this `zip` / `tar` file into Artifactory (using Gradle), but so far everything I see around that subject includes **(1)** the file itself (usually a `jar`), **(2)** module meta-data and **(3)** the `POM` file.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: How do you upload your project to Artifactory? Are you using the Gradle Artifactory plugin to upload your files? Does it have to be in a Gradle command?

Comment: Ideally, it should be with Gradle. Problem with using `cURL` and all the other utilities is that I would have to install them all the time, and they are not quite reliable, so implementing retries and things like that is not something I would like to entertain. In Gradle I'm using the `maven-publish` plugin. I don't know if the JFrog's Artifactory plugin could do this. I can also use Ansible. Another issue is that I'm quite constrained about what I can use or not in those environments when building the pipelines — a story for another day ;)

Comment: Would you consider using the JFrog CLI for this mission?
`curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh && ./jfrog rt u <source> <target> --artifactory-url= --user= --password=`

Comment: @yahavi, thanks for the suggestion! — didn't think about this as an alternative. It looks very much more advanced than `cURL` and the likes. Will give it a whirl and see if I can install it during the pipeline process. I would definitely use it if I can't find a straightforward solution using Ansible. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly answers your question, but an easier approach would be to upload to Artifactory using the JFrog CLI:

```
$ curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io
$ ./jfrog rt upload \
      --url="https://domain.tld" \
      --user="some_user" \
      --password="the_password" \
      file_to_upload.zip path/within/artifactory/to/place/the/file/
```

For more information see [Uploading Files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles).